# What happen if I alloc memory using vzalloc() in kernel but free using kfree()?

Tags: linux-kernel

If I alloc one memory use `vzalloc()` interface (kernel v4.9), but free it use `kfree()`, what will happen in kernel? Can I free this memory?

I watch my code, and see this trouble, but I do not what will happen if touch this problem, so ask others for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `kfree()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/core-api/mm-api.html#c.kfree) says:

> Don’t free memory not originally allocated by `kmalloc()` or you will run into trouble.

If you violate the restriction the behavior is undefined. If you're lucky the kernel will crash; if you're unlucky you might silently corrupt something and cause unspecified future weirdness.

To free memory allocated by `vzalloc()`, use [`vfree()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/core-api/mm-api.html#c.vfree) or [`kvfree()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/core-api/mm-api.html#c.kvfree).

Comment: but i do not know the trouble is what?

Comment: @wtiangshzhu, to understand taht you need to get deeper into memory management and how CPUIs with MMU and without it work. The problem here is the mapping of the address you got, most likely you will have a double or triple fault (CPU exception) and depending on the implementation in the Linux kernel you will have fireworks here or there.